# QNetworkAccessManager freezes GUI even when in another thread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qnetworkaccessmanager

When my program opens, a connection is made to my server via `QNetworkAccessManager::connectToHostEncrypted()` which is called in the constructor of `MainWindow`. This freezes the GUI thread and causes a noticeable delay until the connection is finished. (Sometimes over a full second longer)

This problem is worsened by the fact that my program fades in at startup, so while the GUI thread is blocked, the fade in doesn't start until after the connection is done. In a default Qt project, this is noticeable in other ways like widgets not being painted.

To keep the GUI thread going, I moved `QNetworkAccessManager` into a completely different thread with `QThread` thinking this would solve the issue, however the GUI thread still freezes. This makes no sense to me.

Here is a minimally compilable example project.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QThread>

class Connection : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Connection(QObject *parent) : QNetworkAccessManager(parent){}

public slots:
    void openConnection(){
        connectToHostEncrypted("https://www.url.com");
    }

signals:
    void closeThread(bool);
};


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QThread *connectionThread;
    Connection *connection;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connection = new Connection(this);

    connectionThread = new QThread();
    connection->moveToThread(connectionThread);
    connect(connectionThread, SIGNAL(started()), connection, SLOT(openConnection()));
    connect(connection, SIGNAL(closeThread(bool)), connectionThread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(connectionThread, SIGNAL(finished()), connectionThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    connectionThread->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete connection;
    delete ui;
}
```

This example project creates an instance of `Connection` which is a subclass of `QNetworkAccessManager` that I then move to another thread via `moveToThread()`. This is how I do all my worker threads.

When the thread's `start()` signal is emitted, `openConnection()` calls `connectToHostEncrypted()` which is where the GUI thread freezes.

I have tried just calling a regular HTTP request instead, however the problem persists since an initial connection still needs to be made.

How come the GUI thread still freezes even though the connection is done in another thread?

Answer (score 1):

try to use :

```cpp
connect(connectionThread, SIGNAL(started()), connection, SLOT(openConnection(),Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Comment: Sorry, I did some further testing and it looks like using QueuedConnection is unrelated to the solution. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was I passed `this` as a parent to the `Connection` instance which meant `moveToThread()` couldn't be completed. I just had to check the output log to see that, but I must have missed it!

By removing that parent, the connection was now in it's own thread.

I further tested this by calling `QThread::sleep(3)` inside that `openConnection()` call and there was still no delay.